# How do I make a screen update when a boolean becomes true?

Tags: java, kotlin, button, state, android-jetpack-compose

```
if(isPlayerNearby) {
    Text("Player $playerName is within range!")
    Image(/*some image*/)
    Button(onClick = { attack() }) {
        Text(text = "ELIMINATE")
    }
} else {
    Text("No players nearby. Keep searching.")
    Image(/*some OTHER image*/)
    Button(onClick = { attack() }) { //This button should be DISABLED
        Text(text = "ELIMINATE")
    }
}
```

I have a boolean variable that becomes true if a player is within range, but I'm confused about how I can make the screen live update when this requirement is met. It should switch from disabled to enabled and vice-versa as an opposing player becomes in and out of range.

Here is the code we're using to set isPlayerNearby to true

```
private var endpointDiscoveryCallback: EndpointDiscoveryCallback = object :
    EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
    override fun onEndpointFound(endpointId: String, info: DiscoveredEndpointInfo) {
        toEndpointId = endpointId
        // An endpoint was found. We request a connection to it.
        Nearby.getConnectionsClient(context)
            .requestConnection(getLocalUserName(), endpointId, connectionLifeCycleCallback)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                run {
                    endpointFound()
                    //This is where we will set isPlayerNearby to true
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, endpointId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
//                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Could Not Connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    override fun onEndpointLost(endpointId: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Endpoint Lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Setting the boolean to false will change the screen, but it won't live update - the screen basically needs to be rebuilt to see the results. I believe we have to use states but I am not too familiar.

Answer (score 0):

use LiveData or StateFlow

```
val isPlayerNearby = MutableLiveData(false)


...

       run {
              endpointFound()
              isPlayerNerby.postValue(true)
              Toast.makeText(applicationContext,endpointId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show()
   }
```

in Fragment observe our liveData:

```
  viewModel.isPlayerNearby.observe(viewLifecicleOwner) { isPlayerNearby ->
  
    if(isPlayerNearby) {
        Text("Player $playerName is within range!")
        Image(/*some image*/)
        Button(onClick = { attack() }) {
        Text(text = "ELIMINATE") }
    }else {
        Text("No players nearby. Keep searching.")
        Image(/*some OTHER image*/)
        Button(onClick = { attack() }) { //This button should be DISABLED
        Text(text = "ELIMINATE")
        }
    }
```